# Vagrant heira_config error on vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I'm trying to vagrant up a box, from config files created by puphpet - which has been working fine on my Yosemite 10.10 Macbook Air for a couple of weeks - but having just reloaded the config to add another vhost to apache, I now get the following error(s) when running vagrant up

```
==> default: Installing Puppet requirements
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 54: /usr/bin/gem: No such file or directory
==> default: Finished installing Puppet requirements
==> default: Installing Puppet 3.4.3
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 58: /usr/bin/gem: No such file or directory
==> default: Finished installing Puppet 3.4.3
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with site.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Could not parse options: invalid option: --hiera_config
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

I'm using a `hashicorp/precise64` base box, and my puppet provision is:

```
provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
```

Can anyone shed any light on why I'm suddenly getting this error?

Comment: Removing the heira_config line causes further errors, and I don't know enough about puppet/vagrant to fix those either!

Comment: Having tried with a few different base boxes, I got it to work with puphpet/ubuntu1204-x64 - it seems to fail on any 14.04 base boxes, but works OK with 12.04 boxes

Comment: That's weird. Puppet `3.4.3` has that option. Those `gem` errors are disconcerting. Perhaps the issue is related to them.

Comment: Very weird - @FelixFrank I have a feeling that it is related to the gem issues, even though /usr/bin/gem does exist (though perhaps not during the vagrant up process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your logs with something like `VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up`.

In our case vagrant was complaining about an unsigned `rvm` installation (>=1.26), so we had to download the key in our init script, like:

```
command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | sudo gpg --import -
```

*But the error may vary in your case.*